# How to plot using plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, tidyverse

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dZzu5BPVtzP4y6Leb6712-1C_hBPXjX_/view?usp=sharing

I'm trying to create a interactive bar plot using ploty in R. The link contains the dataset that I'm working.

This is my code but the output is totaly different from what expected

```
df<- read.csv("continental_death_total.csv")


fig <- df %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~continent,
    y = ~continental_sum,
    frame = ~date,
    type = 'bar',
    mode = 'markers',
    showlegend = F
  )

fig
```

> Output
> [image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code with `type = "bar"` (Click on the play button to see the bars on each date):

```
df<- read.csv("continental_death_total.csv")

library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
fig <- df %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~continent,
    y = ~continental_sum,
    frame = ~date,
    type = 'bar',
    showlegend = F
  )

fig
```

Output:

[image]

---

You can check the [docs](https://plotly.com/r/bar-charts/) for more information and examples.

Comment: My date column was in 'date' data type. I converted it to character and it worked